# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, cucumberjs

I am trying to run cucumber tests however, i get the following error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
at Object.relative (path.js:1167:5)
at Object.getDefinitionLineAndUri (/Users/karencardoz/Documents/Workspace/TestCafe/node_modules/cucumber/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/support_code_library_builder/build_helpers.js:24:34)
at /Users/karencardoz/Documents/Workspace/TestCafe/node_modules/cucumber/node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/lib/support_code_library_builder/index.js:80:51
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/karencardoz/Documents/Workspace/TestCafe/features/support/hooks.js:45:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/karencardoz/Documents/Workspace/TestCafe/features/support/errorHandling.js:2:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
```

Karens-MacBook-Pro:TestCafe karencardoz$

---

My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "testcafe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "testcafe"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0",
    "cucumber": "^7.1.0",
    "gradle": "^1.2.4",
    "testcafe": "^1.16.1",
    "testcafe-angular-selectors": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.0.0-rc.1"
  }
```

---

Import format in step def

```
const assert = require('assert');
const { Given, When, Then } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
```

Comment: Can you add your feature file and steps.js ? It's possible a parameter is missing in your feature file based on your steps implementation

Answer (score 1):

At present, TestCafe doesn't have an official integration with Cucumber. Track [this](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2835) issue in the TestCafe's GitHub repository to be informed of its progress.